# How do I call a constructor in a .Service from .Webform?

Tags: c#, html, webforms

Just a quick warning, english is not my first language so I apologize in advance if I explain something poorly. For context, I am in a internship and I have a task to change a very old webform project up to date. The project contains a Library folder (with a ProjectName.Core, a ProjectName.Data, a ProjectName.DataContract and a ProjectName.Service) and a ProjectName.Webform. The problem is that I am working on a file in the ProjectName.Service that requires me to create a config using a file, but the file is in the ProjectName.Webform file/folder and I don't know how to use it. Could anyone help me? I have been working on that project for over 100hours and finally decided to ask for help in stackoverflow.

I am working in a function that is in the ProjectName.Service and I need to call a file situated in the ProjectName.Webform in order to make a new config and create a bearerToken. The problem is that I can't access the file I am supposed to use and I don't know how to call it.

Comment: You are working with more than one class.  You cannot read the config file from a second project.  So you first have to create a class object and read the data from the config file into the class.  Then read the class from 2nd project.  The class either has to be static or you need an instance of the class to read in 2nd project.

Comment: I think I made an error when I said config, I didn't meant that it was a .config file. The name of the file is somethingConfig but it is a .vb file.

Comment: VB or VBnet?  VBnet has class object just like c# and uses Net library.  So same thing applies as c#.  The vbnet is a class object and can be referenced by a c# class provided it is a using Net.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving the files into the .core folder and it works now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).